# Non existence of solution of a certain PDE problem

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my introductory course of PDE appears the following remark without proof.

**It must be observed that if $\mu$ is the first positive eigenvalue (so, there is a postive eigenfunction associated to $\mu$) of minus laplacian operator with zero Dirichlet conditions in a regular and bounded domain $D$, then the following problem has not solution

I have tried to use Fourier transform to obtain this result but I would know if there exists any easier way to prove it.

Comment: Do you know the Fredholm alternative?

Comment: I have read a bit about it. Is not it only for compact operator? I don't see how to apply that result here.

Comment: The operator $L:=\nabla^{2}+\mu$ is self adjoint with the homogeneous boundary conditions i.e $L=L^{*}$. The PDE is then $Lf=-1$. Hence, if $v\in \text{ker }L^{*}$ (i.e $v$ solves $L^{*}v=0$) subject to $v=0$ on $\partial D$, then taking the inner product of both sides with $v$, we have \begin{align}\langle Lf,v\rangle &=\langle f,L^{*}v\rangle\\&=\langle f,0\rangle\\&=0\\&=\langle -1,v\rangle \end{align} So if you solve $L^{*}v=Lv=0, v=0$ on $\partial D$, take the inner product against $-1$ and the result isn't $0$, then no solution exists. Use $$\langle A(x),B(x)\rangle=\int_{U}A(x)B(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Let me rewrite a comment of @mattos in a form which is more accessible for beginners.

Suppose, by contradiction, that your boundary value problem has a solution, say, $f$. 
And let us denote by $\varphi$ a positive eigenfunction associated with $\mu$.

Then, multiplying the equation by $\varphi$ and integrating over $D$, we get
$$
-\int_D \varphi \nabla^2 f \, dx = \mu \int_D f \varphi \,dx + \int_D \varphi \, dx.
$$
Applying the [Divergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions) and recalling that $\varphi,f=0$ on $\partial D$, we see that
$$
-\int_D \varphi \nabla^2 f \, dx = \int_D (\nabla f, \nabla \varphi) \, dx.
$$

On the other hand, since $\varphi$ is the eigenfunction associated with $\mu$, we have, by definition,
$$
-\nabla^2 \varphi = \mu \varphi ~\text{in}~ D, \quad \varphi=0 ~\text{on}~ D.
$$
Hence, multiplying this equation by $f$ and integrating over $D$, we get
$$
-\int_D f\nabla^2 \varphi \, dx \equiv \int_D (\nabla f, \nabla \varphi) \, dx
=
\mu \int_D f \varphi \,dx.
$$

Combining the formulas above, we conclude that
$$
\int_D \varphi \, dx = 0.
$$
But this is impossible since $\varphi$ is strictly positive by assumption (and hence we should have $\int_D \varphi \, dx >0$). Thus, we've got a contradiction, and hence your boundary value problem cannot have a solution.

Comment: This is a great answer, very well explained (+1).